# Как установить вручную индексы в цикле for PHP?

Tags: php, циклы

Как установить вручную все индексы $i в цикле for PHP без всякого шага, чтобы отдельно с каждой переменной не связываться?

```
$a='5_s';
$c='5_l';
$b='5_m';
for($i='s','m','l') {
  echo '5_'.$i;
}
```

Comment: а что должно получиться?

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос. Если вы хотите перебрать массив - то для этого есть foreach

Comment: Массива нет. Нужно просто пройтись циклом по переменным, имеющим сходные строки в значении

Comment: @ArturHan вы бы оформили свой вопрос так: _Есть такие-то переменные. Нужно привести их к такому-то виду_ -- тогда можно было бы визуально посмотреть на требуемый результат и написать решение. А в данный момент вас понимают только ... вы.

Comment: Я немного исправил вопрос. Есть переменные, имеющие общую часть. И чтобы с ними не связываться, как использовать цикл?Я их привел только для наглядности.

Comment: в вашем коде то `foreach(['s', 'm', 'l'] as $i)  ` то не пойдет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Есть переменные, имеющие общую часть. И чтобы с ними не связываться, как использовать цикл?*

```
$a = '5_s';
$c = '5_l';
$b = '5_m';

foreach (get_defined_vars() as $defined_var) {
    if (is_string($defined_var) && substr($defined_var, 0, 2) == '5_') {
        echo $defined_var . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
5_s
5_l
5_m
```